# jquery, asp.net ajax, javascript not executing at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollfix");
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                __doPostBack('<%= GetMoreResults.UniqueID %>', '');
            }
            $scrollingDiv
                .stop()
                .animate({ "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + -60 + "px" }, "slow");
        });
    }
</script>
```

This code does not execute at all, the reason i'm using the pageLoad function is because the jquery code failed to execute after updatepanel partial postback.
But then after using this one, none of the code above works even on first page startup.

However, the code that USED to work on page load is below but the jquery part STOPPED working after postback:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $().ready(function () {
        var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollfix");
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                __doPostBack('<%= GetMoreResults.UniqueID %>', '');
            }
            $scrollingDiv
            .stop()
            .animate({ "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + -60 + "px" }, "slow");
        });
    });
});
```

Solutions? Thanks alot.

### UPDATE #2

This is my current code:
It works the first time the page loads, but not after the partial postback trigger by the __doPostBack.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.load = pageLoad();
            function pageLoad() { 
                var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollfix"); 
                $(window).scroll(function () { 
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) { 
                        __doPostBack('<%= GetMoreResults.UniqueID %>', ''); 
                    } 
                    $scrollingDiv 
                    .stop() 
                    .animate({ "marginTop": eval($(window).scrollTop()) + -60 + "px" }, "slow"); 
                }); 
            } 
</script>
```

### UPDATE #3

I should mention that this page does not inherit from Page, I've made a custom page class called BasePage : Page.

Maybe pageLoad() does not fire for some reason related to this?

Comment: Do you even call pageLoad() anywhere?

Comment: You can remove $().ready(function () {

Comment: Be more specific, what is not working, can you alert inside .scroll function?

Comment: pageLoad() is called automagically if you're using ASP.NET ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using .bind() with your `pageLoad`:

**pageLoad:**

> It is also called after every partial postback. It basically functions
>   as a combination of Application.Init and
>   PageRequestManager.EndRequest.

```
   function pageLoad() {
        var $scrollingDiv = $("#scrollfix");
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            __doPostBack('<%= GetMoreResults.UniqueID %>', '');
            }
            $scrollingDiv
            .stop()
            .animate({ "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + -60 + "px" }, "slow");
        });
    }
```

[$(document).ready() and pageLoad() are not the same!](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

Comment: Nope I tried the same thing with bind and live, doesn't execute.

Comment: Hey Rick, thanks again for the answer, I tried it with pageLoad not with $(document).ready(), that's whats confusing me. It used to work on other projects. I'm gonna try to narrow down the code to check if pageLoad is called each time.

Comment: turns out I do have a conflict, using pageLoad() elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

That code won't execute unless you assign it to the `window.onload` event:

```
window.onload = pageLoad;
```

I would also consider wrapping the calculation of the top margin with the `eval` function:

```
eval($(window).scrollTop() - 60) + "px"
```

Lastly, I don't see any need for the second ready state function:

```
$().ready(function () {
```

Comment: I think the pageLoad() fuction is provided by the ASP.NET ScriptManager and can be used anywhere automatically. But I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: get rid of the () after pageLoad; you are assigning a function variable to another, not executing a function.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript knows nothing about partial page postbacks; that's an ASP.NET wrapper around an AJAX form post that returns HTML content.  If you want your `pageLoad` to be called after partial page postbacks, you'll have to register a client script that calls `pageLoad` in your postback handler.  You'll also need to ensure that the function is called upon your first page load, as @James Johnson pointed out.